# why my validation rules in trait are not working when i call it from controller?

Tags: php, laravel

this us my trait. validation rules are not working even i give 1 for the page number getting
response not validation error.

```
trait ValidatePagination
            {
protected function pagination(Request $request)
{ 
    $rules['page'] = 'integer|gt:4';
    $rules['per_page'] = 'integer|gt:0|lte:100';
    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

   if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors(), Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
    }
}
```

}

my controller's method

```
  public function get(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
   $companyId = $request['user']->cid;
    $perPage = $request->query('per_page', 15);
    
    $this->pagination($request);

    $staffTable = TableBuilder::get($companyId, STAFF);

    $staff = $staffTable->get(['pid', 'name', 'mobile', 'pay_rate', 'is_working', 'pay_start_date', 'pay_end_date']);
    $staff = $staffTable->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate($perPage);

    return $this->success('Fetched staff members', $staff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you are not using the returned data, you should throw an exception instead, this is kinda tricky to get the correct data into the validation exception. The most correct approach is to use form requests, which you can also reuse across controllers.

The request can be created by using `php artisan make:request PaginatedRequest`. For further information see the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation).

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class PaginatedRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'page' => 'integer|gt:4',
            'per_page' => 'integer|gt:0|lte:100',
        ];
    }
}
```

This will automatically resolve the validator and throw the correct exception. The pattern is also recommended as a good practice in [Laravel best practices](https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#validation).

```
public function get(PaginatedRequest $request): JsonResponse
{
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should return the failed validation inside `get` function also like so:

```php
public function get(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
   $companyId = $request['user']->cid;
    $perPage = $request->query('per_page', 15);
    
    if ($validatorValue = $this->pagination($request)) {
        return $validatorValue;
    }

    $staffTable = TableBuilder::get($companyId, STAFF);

    $staff = $staffTable->get(['pid', 'name', 'mobile', 'pay_rate', 'is_working', 'pay_start_date', 'pay_end_date']);
    $staff = $staffTable->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')->simplePaginate($perPage);

    return $this->success('Fetched staff members', $staff);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like you are missing returning the validation error from the controller code. An easy fix would be to run the validate instead of the fails code. I would say the most correct approach would be @mrhn solution since you should ideally create a FormRequest.

```
trait ValidatePagination
{
    protected function pagination(Request $request)
    { 
        $rules['page'] = 'integer|gt:4';
        $rules['per_page'] = 'integer|gt:0|lte:100';
        $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

        $validator->validate();
    }
```